# Migrating to spring 3.1.4 and Hibernate 4.2.8 SpringSessionContext.currentSession throws HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, migration

I'm migrating to spring 3.1.4 and Hibernate 4.2.8 and all of my dao and services classes are annotated with `@Transactional` correctly (my application works correctly with spring 3.0.7 and Hibernate 3.6)

but when I migrate to these versions, my Transactional methods annotated with `Propagation.SUPPORTS` throws an `HibernateException` alerting that there are no session found for current thread..

this happens inside the `SpringSessionContext.currentSession()` method.. I noticed that it does not create a session if `TransactionSynchronizationManager` does not contain one..

when I annotate the method with `Propagation.REQUIRED` all happens correctly..

I've tested for Spring 3.2.5 and the bug persists.